# Make Magento 2 Module installable from github/bitbucket

Tags: extensions, magento2, composer

I want to make my extension, say [Easy Template Path Hints](https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints) which is available on github(may be on bitbucket someday) installable via composer. Tried many variation but it's not working.

Here are some of my attempts

**1. Using following series of composer commands**

```
composer config repositories.magepsycho git https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints.git
composer require magepsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints:1.0.0
```

This resulted in error

> The requested package magepsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints
>   could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package
>   name.

**2. Manually editing the composer.json**

Added the following under "require" node

```
"magepsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints": "master"
```

And the following under "repositories" node

```
"magepsycho": {
    "type":"package",
    "package": {
        "name": "magepsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints",
        "version":"master",
        "source": {
            "url": "https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints.git",
            "type": "git",
            "reference":"master"
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
composer update
```

There was no any error and it successfully downloaded the extension under `vendor` folder. But was not installed in `app/code` folder

May be listing the module to packagist.org may help but I want it to be installable via git also.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: can you tell me how to make my module available in github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by using following commands:

```
composer config repositories.magesycho-magento2-easy-template-path-hints git git@github.com:MagePsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints.git
composer require magepsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints:dev-master
```

## Explanation

Before I was using `magepsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints:1.0.0` instead of `magepsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints:dev-master`.

If you are loading a package from VCS repository (git, svn etc.), version should be a branch name prefixed with `dev-`

Source: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs

Comment: Currently your repo does not have a tagged version. Once you add a tag, for example 0.5.0 or v0.5.0, you can just use `composer require magepsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints` and composer will install the last version for you.

Comment: Sounds interesting! Will give a try.

Comment: You should remove this answer as it's really misinformation.  You should not load a package from a VCS repository using a branch name if at all possible.

Comment: @Navarr can you add the correct answer to this?

Comment: @paj I have an answer at the top of the list?

Answer (score 2):

For a private repository, you would want to do what you've already done - which is create a repository directive in your composer.json and require it.  You would then ideally use git tags to mark your versions.

For a public repository, like what you actually have - you have a few misconceptions about how Magento 2 and composer work together.

One big thing of note is that *composer packages aren't in app/code, and you don't want them there*.  Instead, they install directly to the vendor/ directory and stay there.  This allows any code in app/code/ to be specific to your environment and keeps your installation clean.

Looking at your repository, you have two composer.json files - I understand why, since your goal was to get the code copies into app/code, but with the information that you shouldn't be doing that, you can (and should) remove the composer.json from the src/ directory.  You'll then need to change your base directory composer.json's file require directive to point to "src/registration.php" instead of just "registration.php"

Once you've done that, it should load in to vendor/ when required, and should be accessible for module:enable and in Magento itself.

The next step, since this appears to be a public extension - is to add it to Packagaist.  Packagist is the default repository in composer, and adding it to Packagist allows its use without defining a new vcs repository type.

You can submit it to Packagist here: https://packagist.org/packages/submit - it will require an account, and if you read carefully packagist will help walk you through setting up your repository to automatically inform packagist of new versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in in `composer.json` on the same level as `repositories`

```
extra": {
    "map": [
        [
            "*",
            "MagePsycho/EasyTemplatePathHints"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's there: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MagePsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints/master/composer.json